# Scopes and blocks

Tags: ruby, scope

In ruby, `module`, `class`, and `def` keywords define a new scope. I'm confused as to why local variables defined in a block do not exist outside of the block. Is a block argument another scope gate? For example:

```
(1..2).each { |n| numer = 'czesc' }
numer # => NameError: undefined local variable or method `czesc' for main:Object
```

Or more simply:

```
def kon; end
kon { kot = 3 }
kot # => NameError: undefined local variable or method `kot' for main:Object
```

I thought, maybe it's not persisted because it's defined in the method's arguments, but the following works for the normal arguments:

```
def pokaz(cos)
  p cos
end
pokaz(co = "to")
co # => "to"
```

Comment: humm.. Keep playing with Ruby.. It is amazing.. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In ruby, `module`, `class`, and `def` keywords define a new scope.

There are six scope constructs in Ruby: module bodies, class bodies, method bodies and script bodies create new scopes, block bodies and "stabby lambda" literal bodies create new nested scopes.

> I'm confused as to why local variables defined in a block do not exist outside of the block.

Because a block body has its own lexical scope. The scope is nested, which means that it has access to local variables from the outer scope, but variables from an inner scope never leak into the outer scope.

Comment: when you say "script bodies", are you referring to code in different files? Also, I always read about there being the "three scope gates" I listed. Do you know where I could find this information? It could lead me to other gems!

Comment: Yes, unlike other languages where local variables at the top level are actually global, in Ruby they are local to the script, i.e. the file. By "scope gates", I guess they mean they create *new* scopes, whereas blocks and `->` lambda literals nest.

Answer (score 4):

You might think about codeblocks as of lazy instances of [`Proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Proc.html) class.

Your second example with `kon`/`kot` does actually not what you were expecting from it. You supply a codeblock to a function `kon`. This codeblock *is not evaluated* unless requested. In your snippet it is never evaluated. Look:

```
▶ def kon; end
#⇒ :kon
▶ kon { puts 'I am here' }
#⇒ nil
```

You passed a codeblock. Fine. Now `kon` should invoke it, if needed:

```
▶ def kon; yield ; end
#⇒ :kon
▶ kon { puts 'I am here' }
# I am here
#⇒ nil
```

When you passed a codeblock to, say, `each` method of `Enumerator` instance:

```
(1..2).each { |n| numer = 'czesc' }
```

The codeblock is being evaluated in context of this `Enumerator`. The default receiver, `self`, is still the main thread, though. That makes codeblocks to act mostly like closures (they have an access to the caller bindings):

```
▶ kot = 10  
#⇒ 10
▶ 5.times do |i|  
▷   kot = i  
▷ end      
▶ puts kot
#⇒ 4
```

Hope it sheds some light.

Comment: Great information about codeblocks being lazily evaluated. Poor example on my part, then!