# Ruby, understanding local variables scope in if block

Tags: ruby, binding, scope

I have detected an unexpected behaviour in a variable declaration into an `if` block:

```
puts "local_variables: #{local_variables}"
puts "defined? my_variable ini: #{defined? my_variable}"

if true
  my_variable = 1
  puts "local_variables in the 'if' block: #{local_variables}"
end

1.times do
  my_variable_2 = 1
  puts "local_variables in the 'times' block: #{local_variables}"
  puts "defined? my_variable_2 in the 'times' block: #{defined? my_variable_2}"
end

puts "defined? my_variable_2 end: #{defined? my_variable_2}"
puts "defined? my_variable end: #{defined? my_variable}"
puts "my_variable: #{my_variable}"
```

The result is:

```
local_variables: [:my_variable]
defined? my_variable ini: 
local_variables in the 'if' block: [:my_variable]
local_variables in the 'times' block: [:my_variable_2, :my_variable]
defined? my_variable_2 in the 'times' block: local-variable
defined? my_variable_2 end: 
defined? my_variable end: local-variable
my_variable: 1
```

Questions:

1. variables declared into `if` block become accesible from outside the `if` block, is this correct? why it looks counter-intuitive for me?
2. why the `times` block behaviour is different to the `if` block?

I have been reading [this documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variable+Scope) but I don't see the `if` block case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ruby, classes, modules, functions, blocks and procs all have their own scope, so local variables defined within them will not normally be accessible outside of them.

In ruby, logic statements such as *if*, *while* and *for* do not have their own scope, so variables defined in them persist in the class, module, function block, or proc where they're used.

This is a design choice and part of what makes ruby ruby! It may feel counter-intuitive because languages like c have separate scopes for *if* statements and some (but not all) interpreted languages mimic that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, `if` does not introduce a new scope, so variables can be used outside
2. `times` takes a block, and a block introduces a new scope.

To learn more about scope gates please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29554824/2969217)